# Unable to deploy Integration Service from Integration Studio to Service Catalog of WSO2 APIM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-integration-studio

Added the following to the embedded MI's toml:

```
[[service_catalog]]
apim_host = "https://localhost:9443"
enable = true
username = "xxxxxxxx"
password = "xxxxxxxx"
```

Made sure the metadata and swagger files are present. Then clicked *Export Project Artifacts and Run*. But I don't see any *Publish to Service Catalog* checkbox that's supposed to be there according to this [doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/tutorials/integration-tutorials/service-catalog-tutorial/).

The first time I tried, I got the following error (implying it's trying to publish?):

```
ERROR {ServiceCatalogUtils} - Error occurred while reading the response from service catalog javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:198)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1967)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:331)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:325)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1688)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:226)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1082)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:1010)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1079)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1388)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1400)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.utils.ServiceCatalogUtils.getAllServices(ServiceCatalogUtils.java:209)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.serviceCatalog.ServiceCatalogExecutor.run(ServiceCatalogExecutor.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:285)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:237)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1670)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:233)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:80)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:375)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:457)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifySignature(BasicChecker.java:166)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:147)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
    ... 31 more
```

So I imported the APIM certificate into the embedded MI's trust store. The **error disappeared** but I don't see *Successfully updated the service catalog* either. And when I check in the Services tab of the APIM, my service is not there.

Am I missing any steps? Or doing anything wrong?

Comment: Did you do the points mentioned in [Step 4](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/tutorials/integration-tutorials/service-catalog-tutorial/#step-4-package-the-artifacts)? Make sure the API and the Endpoint are selected in the pom.xml of the `CompositeExporter` module. Also, that is the screen where you will see the `Publish to Service Catalog` checkbox.

Comment: @HisanHunais, I have selected the artefacts I need and continued but I don't see the check box - I'm using Integration studio 8.0.0. Is it an issue with this version? Or can you link me to an image where this is shown.

Comment: The `Publish to Service Catalog` checkbox is available in Integration studio 8.1.0. What is the APIM version you are using?

Comment: @HisanHunais, APIM 4.1.0. I think it tries to publish even with studio 8.0.0, since I get a certificate error. But I don't know why after importing the certificate it doesn't publish! Is there a manual way of placing the CAR in the service catalog?

Comment: Did you restart the MI server after publishing the CAR to Micro Integrator? MI 4.1.0 supports hot deployment for Service Catalog. (ie no need to restart). If it is MI 4.0.0, then you need to restart the MI server. (PS: Integration Studo 8.0.0 has MI 4.0.0 embedded)